# ¿Cómo generar un archivo PDF con datos dinámicos y enviarlo por correo en PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, email

Estoy trabajando en una plataforma donde los usuarios puedan registrarse a un torneo, y necesito enviarle un correo de confirmación con sus datos en un pdf, estoy utilizando php, espero me puedan ayudar, un saludo :)

Comment: Cual es tu pregunta, ya intentaste hacer algo?

Comment: Puedes utilizar la clase TCPDF y la clase PhpMailer.